# How to generate TypeScript UML class diagrams in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, uml, class-diagram

Are there any tools that can generate a UML class diagram from a project in TypeScript or a similar language?

Comment: You should really ask 2 questions, one for each language... I doubt the syntax is so similar that one tool would work for both.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **UML Diagram** feature introduced by **IntelliJ** Editor by **Jetbrains** and it works very well with typescript.

## Open the Diagram Popup

Go to **Settings** >>> **Search for uml** and find the keyboard shortcut for it.

**OR**

Right Click on a class name >>> **Diagrams** >>> **Show Diagram Popup**

## Show class properties and methods:

Righ Click on the diagram popup >>> Show Categories >>> **Methods** `or` **Properties**

### Tips

- You will find many options to show through the right click on the diagram popup.
- You can zoom on the diagram objects (If there are too much details) by holding the **Alt** key when hovering on them

  [image]

Comment: Question asks for VS code.

Comment: @PaulJohnLeonard Please don't be quick to judge. I have just checked the history https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17931892/revisions and you can see that the question title has been updated 2 years after the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For TypeScript:

- The **ALM TypeScript editor** includes this feature: 
  https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/issues/84

  However it looks like it only creates diagram for a single class, not a full hierarchical view of the project with inheritance relationships.
- **Tsviz** is another promising project: https://github.com/joaompneves/tsviz

  [image: example generated diagram]

  It generates full project diagram. However it looks outdated and doesn't work with recent TypeScript versions. I'm working on an updated fork.